# Удаление тега и изменение текста при выводе категории

Tags: php, html, wordpress

В теме на WordPress есть запись:

```
public function get_categories( $sep = ', ', $before = '', $after = '' ) {
    return get_the_term_list( $this->id, 'product_cat', $before, $sep, $after );
}
global $product;
echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">Назад:', '</span>' );
```

Которая выводит ссылку на *"Название категории"* в теге `span`:

```
<span class="posted_in"> <a href="#" rel="tag">Назад: Название категории</a></span>
```

Вторую часть вопроса мне удалось сделать, т.е. добавить к ссылке слово `Назад:`.
Теперь задача сводится к тому, чтобы исключить тег `span`из разметки, но сохранить при этом `class="posted_in"`, который передать ссылке, т.к. при такой записи за счет `span` не вся область кликабельна, а только при наведении на ссылку, что не является допустимым поведением. Если же просто вычеркнуть тег `span` из разметки, то ссылка видна в структуре, но на экране монитора не отображается..
Есть варианты как это можно сделать?

Comment: Какая ошибка и что такое `_n()`?

Comment: И как получилось, что `'<span class="posted_in">' . _n() . ' '` и `'</span>'` - это разные параметры, передаваемую в функцию? И, кстати, что делает эта функция `get_categories()`?

Comment: @Regent функции get_categories() - http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_categories и _n() - http://wp-kama.ru/function/_n
стандартные. ошибка сигнализирующая, что в php файле ошибка

Comment: А зачем здесь используется `_n()`? В коде ей не передаются никакие параметры (при том, что 3 параметра у неё обязательные, судя по приведённой статье) и, судя по итоговому HTML, она из-за этого возвращает пустую строку. Упомянутая в другой статье `get_categories` вряд ли имеет что-то общее с `$product->get_categories`: во-первых, передаваемые аргументы у них сильно разнятся, во-вторых, `$product->` намекает на то, что `get_categories` - это метод внутри класса, которому принадлежит объект `$product`. Поэтому вопросы про `get_categories` и `_n()` остаются в силе.

Comment: @Regent да, вы правы - нашел переопределение функции `get_categories()`, вписал выше

Comment: а у _n() переопределений нет

Comment: мне вроде бы удалось сделать так: `echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span>Назад:' . _n() . ' ', '</span>' );` чтобы вывелось так, как хотел, но это ведь не логично - да?

Comment: Нелогично, потому что вы сами в вопросе написали, что не хотите, чтобы был `<span>`. Если вам действительно нужно только `<a href="#" rel="tag">Назад: Название категории</a>`, то стоит разбираться с `get_the_term_list` - искать, как в неё добавить _"Назад"_. А вызов `get_categories` сделать таким: `$product->get_categories();`.

Comment: @Regent, судя по названию, `_n()` может быть функцией вывода локализованной строки. да, [угадал](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n). больше о [локализации](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/internationalization/localization/).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin может-может, только, видимо, локализованной строки в данном примере нет. Я, вообще говоря, не против неё. Но суть проблемы ведь в другом.

Comment: @Regent, ну, я исключительно для справки (и дополнил пред. комментарий ссылками). а то, что параметров нет, возможно, и нормально: зависит от реализации этой функции (копаться лень).

Comment: @Regent, локализованной строки там, при вызове функции, **точно** не должно быть. локализованные строки хранятся в `.po` и `.pot`. это стандарт локализации, принятый в проекте *gnu* для *glibc*, он используется и в огромном количестве других проектов. вот, в частности, в *wordpress-е*.

Comment: @Regent, я уже давно не занимался локализациями, но, насколько помню, в *php* может быть реализована привязка к номеру и/или содержимому строки. поэтому после изменения порядкового номера и/или содержимого строки с одной из «локализующих» функций (начинающихся обычно с символа `_`), надо заново регенерировать файлы с локализацией (это должно быть описано по ссылке, приведённой мною выше). аналогично надо регенерировать файлы `.po` (`.mo`, по идее, в *php*-реализациях *gettext-а* не используется) и после внесения исправления в файлы `.pot` (их, собственно, переводчики и правят, емнип).

Comment: @Regent по сути `get_the_term_list` - это стандартная непереопределенная функция http://wp-kama.ru/function/get_the_term_list, но знание ее параметров мне ничего не дает, т.к. в ней используются `get_the_term_list( $this->id, 'product_cat', $before, $sep, $after )`-> id, таксономия=категория, разделитель и теги до/после. а мне по сути нужно воткнуть сюда `'<span>Назад:' . _n() . ' '` слово `Назад:` не используя `span`, ибо span мне не устраивает тем, что не по всей области он кликабелен..

Comment: @Regent функция локализации оказалась действительно не причем, в связи с чем видоизменил вопрос выше

Comment: @Вася если на формирование HTML в `get_the_term_list` повлиять нельзя, то можно либо отказаться от её использования, собирая HTML с помощью других функций или вручную, либо применить костыльное решение, меняя HTML уже в самом браузере с помощью JS.

Comment: @Regent а если мы знаем, что `get_categories` возвращает строку в таком виде
`<span class="posted_in"> <a href="#" rel="tag">Назад: Название категории</a></span>` мы ведь можем перезаписать класс в ссылку, а `span` удалить с помощью php или нет?

Comment: @Вася PHP умеет работать со строками, да. Можно или рег. выражение использовать, или аналогию `substring`.

Answer (score 1):

А если так?

```
public function get_categories($sep = ', ', $before = '', $after = '') {
  return get_the_term_list($this->id, 'product_cat', $before, $sep, $after);
}

global $product;
echo $product->get_categories(', ', 'Назад: ', '');
```

Comment: я уже писал в самом описании вопроса, что
`Если же просто вычеркнуть тег span из разметки, то ссылка видна в структуре, но на экране монитора не отображается..` в данном случае, что span, что div одно и тоже..
если бы так все просто было..