# Как перенести содержимое в другой тег с помощью php?

Tags: php, html, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет. Есть html код:

```
<div class="product-prev-button">Назад: 
   <a href="http://cite.ru/catalog/name_category/"  rel="tag">Категория</a>
</div>
```

С помощью php функции `preg_replace()`

```
    $patterns[0] = "/<div class=\"product-prev-button\">/";
    $patterns[1] = "/Назад:/";
    $patterns[2] = "/<\/div>/";
    $patterns[3] = "/<a /";
    $patterns[4] = "/rel=\"tag\">/";

    $replacements[4] = "";
    $replacements[3] = "";
    $replacements[2] = "";
    $replacements[1] = "<a class=\"product-prev-button\"";
    $replacements[0] = "rel=\"tag\">Назад: ";

    $str_get_categories_format = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str_get_categories_no_format);
    echo $str_get_categories_format;
```

Прошу обратить внимание, что здесь проблема связана с тем, что слово `назад` находится ДО, + сама ссылка динамическая, а не просто `#` - а это все меняет!
Как можно вставить содержимое тега `div` - `Назад` внутрь ссылки?
Решено. Получилась вот такая запись:

```
 <a href="http://cite.ru/catalog/name_category/" class="product-prev-button" rel="tag">Назад: Категория</a>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [С помощью регулярного выражения привести строку к нужному виду](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435560/%d0%a1-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d1%83)

Comment: Пора кончать плодить однотипные вопросы и выучить регулярные выражения. И хоть бы ответы принимал.

Comment: Опишите, что вас вообще заставляет заниматься этим преобразованием.

Comment: @Qwertiy - это не однотипные вопросы. 
если бы моя проблема была решена - я бы не продолжал ее исследовать и вопросы не однотипные, т.к. слово `назад` в первом случае находится внутри ссылки, а во втором ДО,+ сама ссылка динамическая, а не просто `#` - а это все меняет, теперь это содержимое `div` а не `a` и преобразование такое не проходит

Comment: @ Etki необходимый вид ссылки заставляет - разве это не очевидно..?

Comment: Это почти одно и то же. Здесь немного не сайт "поменяй предыдущую регулярку за минуту и запости ответ". Кстати, я тебе уже и на первый вопрос предположил, что там должно быть.

Comment: Слово "назад" небольшое изменение вносит - добавляется группа и остальные сдвигаются на одну. Многострочность меняет `.` на `[\s\S]`. Всё. "#" вообще ничего не меняет, поскольку мой код в том вопросе всегда сохранял оригинальную ссылку.

Comment: @Qwertiy не соглашусь, что одно и тоже - здесь сложнее, свои аргументы я привел выше. Если вы заметили, то у меня регулярка в итоге своя, не из тех, что мне давали в ответе. Я вам уже отписался, что хочу все провернуть без скриптов - именно поэтому и указываю php в вопросе

Comment: @Etki, http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435380/178988

Comment: Вообще ни разу не очевидно. Зачем вам вообще что-то вытаскивать из ссылки? У вас так этих данных нет?

Comment: @Etki для того, чтобы все область `Назад: Категория` была кликабельной, а не только `Категория`, если все оставить так как есть

Comment: Так а зачем сразу ее нормальной не построить?

Comment: @Etki что по вашему нормальной? получаем из базы wordpress в виде `ссылка: название категории` и форматируем ее под свои нужды - что тут неясного

Comment: Не надо дописывать в заголовок "(решено)". Вместо этого надо принимать ответ. В списке у вопросов с принятым ответом количество ответов написано жёлтым, а не белым.

Comment: @Qwertiy а чей принимать ответ - свой? но у меня нет на это полномочий..примите тогда его пожалуйста

Comment: Принять ответ может только тот, кто задал вопрос. Где-то была тема, что даже модераторы не могут. Чтобы принять свой ответ, должно пройти два дня. Вроде об этом явно пишется в соответствующем сообщении при попытке прниятия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее, у вас должно выводиться вот так вот 
    Назад:Категория
Но слово "назад" прячется где-то в другом месте на странице (чисто предположение).
Чтобы запихнуть слово "Назад" в ссылку, вам необходимо открывающий `div` заменить на открытие ссылки, а, собственно, открытие ссылки заменить на пустоту.

Примерно вот таким образом:

```
 $patterns[0] = "/<a href=\"http://cite.ru/catalog/name_category/\"  rel=\"tag\">/";
 $patterns[1] = "/<\/div>/";
 $patterns[2] = "/<div class=\"product-prev-button\">/";

 $replacements[2] = "";
 $replacements[1] = "";
 $replacements[0] = "<a href=\"http://cite.ru/catalog/name_category/\"  rel=\"tag\">";

 $vic = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str_get_categories_no_format);
 echo $vic;
```

Сначала убираем открытие ссылки и закрытие `div`. А после этого заменяем открытие `div` на открытие ссылки.

Comment: стоп. так не пойдет - у меня ссылка `href=\"http://cite.ru/catalog/name_category/\"` каждый раз разная, ее напрямую так нельзя менять

Comment: Суть остаётся та же, просто необходимо адаптировать это решение под ваш случай.

Comment: То  есть, сначала, к примеру, определить, какая ссылка там внутри находится, а потом перенести её 
Либо, как вариант, не переносить ссылку за слово "назад", а наоборот, перенести слово "назад" в ссылку.
Для этого достаточно в вашем исходном скрипте, который вы запостили, в `$pattern[0]` добавить слово "Назад",чтобы оно стопроцентно убралось, и добавить ещё один паттерн `$pattern[3] = "/rel=\"tag\">/"`, для которого реплейс будет вот таким `$replace = "/rel=\"tag\">Назад: /"`.

Comment: да, чуть-чуть ошиблись, но подход правильный - все заработало! спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

```
'<div class="product-prev-button">Назад: \n\
   <a href="http://cite.ru/catalog/name_category/"  rel="tag">Категория</a>\n\
</div>'
.replace(/<div\s+(class=(["']?)[\s\S]*\2)\s*>\s*([\s\S]*?)<a\s+(href=(["']?)[\s\S]*\5)\s+(rel=(["']?)tag\7)\s*>([\s\S]*?)<\/a>\s*<\/div>/, "<a $4 $1 $6>$3$8</a>")

//<a href="http://cite.ru/catalog/name_category/" class="product-prev-button" rel="tag">Назад: 
//   Категория</a>
```

Comment: спасибо, но хочу обойтись без скрипта, т.к. в этом случае это костыль

Comment: @Вася Эм.. Ты не можешь взять эту же замену и использовать её в php вместо js? Я вот просто php не знаю, чтобы на нём ответ дать, а у тебя в чём проблема??

Answer (score 1):

тяжелее всего было понять ваш вопрос. советую пользоваться ресурсом https://regex101.com/ (или подобными), и вопросы с регулярками сразу все исчезнут:

```
$string = <<<_END
   <div class="product-prev-button">Назад: 
      <a href="http://cite.ru/catalog/name_category/"  rel="tag">Категория</a>
   </div>"
_END;
$patterns = "/<div(.+?)>(.+?)\s+<a(.+?)>(.+)/ms";
$replace  = "<div><a\3\1>\2 \4";
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $string);
```

получаем:

`<div><a href="http://cite.ru/catalog/name_category/"  rel="tag" class="product-prev-button">Назад: Категория</a> </div>`